# analysis of bank account record

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I am new to the field of time series analysis, but I would like to have a look at my bank account and determine my spending habits.

I read a lot about clustering of multiple time series but I think I need to decomposition /break up only one (my cashflow) time series into its patterns and then classify them.

Could you point me into the right direction? / recommend some R packages for this purpose.

Comment: Not going to work. There's too much idiosyncrasy in individual account flows, that's why they're always modeled in pools. Get the cash flows and look at them in Excel or something that shows you graphs. There are tools for spending analysis, such as Mint.com, I don't recommend this one particularly, but you can find many similar ones.

Comment: But aren't there some pretty distinct spending habits & income?

Comment: You don't need statistics for this. You need good data collection, tagging of expenses and graphing by groups.

Comment: Even if I would be interested in forecasting expenses you think graphing them will do the trick?

Comment: I think you won't need anything beyond the simplest regression such as one in Excel. Even that would be overkill. To change your spending habits it's enough to look at charts of your past spending. The horror will be so deep, that your behavior will change immediately.